# x86 assembly: Output from swap function is incorrect even when the implementation is correct

Tags: assembly, swap, x86-16

I've been working on a swap function in order or eventually implement bubble sort using x86 assembly.

My code also includes a function which refactors given number ( from - to + and vise versa ) for another function later, which I've called before testing the swap function

This is the code so far:

```
org  100h
jmp main

    numToNeg dw -9
    toSwap1 db 'a'
    toSwap2 db 'b'

    param1 equ 8 
    swap1 equ 12
    swap2 equ 14



main: 

    push offset numToNeg
    call refactor

    mov ax, numToNeg
    call print_num     

    PRINTN 

    PRINTN "Before Swap:"

    mov al, toSwap1
    Call print_al_chr ;This function prints the given char inside al
    mov al, toSwap2
    Call print_al_chr 

    push offset toSwap1
    push offset toSwap2

    call swap

    PRINTN

    PRINTN "After Swap:"

    mov al, toSwap1
    Call print_al_chr
    mov al, toSwap2
    Call print_al_chr

PROC refactor 
    push bp
    push bx
    push ax
    mov bp, sp  

    mov bx, [bp + param1] 
    mov ax, [bx]

    not ax
    inc ax 

    mov [bx], ax     

    pop ax
    pop bx
    pop bp
    retn 2

ENDP refactor  

PROC swap 
    push bp
    push ax
    push cx
    push bx
    push di

    mov di, [bp + swap1]
    mov ax, [di]
    mov bx, [bp + swap2]
    mov cx, [bx]
    mov [bx], ax
    mov [di], cx

    pop di
    pop bx
    pop cx
    pop ax
    pop bp
    retn 4
ENDP swap
```

Now I'm 100% sure that the swap function is correct, so the problem is somewhere in my main function, but I couldn't figure that out by myself. The stack looked alright to me when i debugged the code and I'm pretty stumped right now :/

To be clear, The function "print_al_chr" Is indeed working, and the implementation is inside another file I'm importing each time. At the start I thought that the problem might be with the 'equ' that I was using at the start, but I'm pretty sure that the values I have passed are indeed correct, because that in the function I'm pushing 5 registers, which takes 10 bytes of space overall, so the parameters should be in the 12 and 14 position.

Thanks :D

Edit: The problem was that I was using 16 bit registers instant of 8 bit registers ( AH and CL Instant of AX and CX ), I also forgot to set BP at the start of the function like I did in the refactor function. Thanks everybody for being patient and helpful :D

Comment: Unrelated, but are you aware that your elaborate (and confusingly named) `refactor` function can be replaced with a single `neg` instruction?

Comment: Oh i forgot to clarify that i couldn't use neg xD, thank you anyway

Comment: Did you actually get it to work? The too large registers used were just one problem here.

Comment: I changed the registers but it is still not working ;( I changed them to cl and ah as suggested but I noticed that I cant push the registers inside my function, So I haven't pushed them and just changed my equ values, but it is still not working :(

Comment: As Michael Petch pointed out in the other thread, you can still `push ax` and `push cx`. This will make your function preserve all of `ax`, `ah`, `al`, `cx`, `cl`, and `ch`, because `ah` and `al` are parts of `ax`, and likewise for `cx`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are missing a `mov bp, sp` in this function:

```
PROC swap 
    push bp
    push ax
    push cx
    push bx
    push di

    mov di, [bp + swap1]
```

---

You reserved one byte for each variable:

```
    toSwap1 db 'a'
    toSwap2 db 'b'
```

But then you used 16-bit word loads and stores:

```
    mov di, [bp + swap1]
    mov ax, [di]
    mov bx, [bp + swap2]
    mov cx, [bx]
    mov [bx], ax
    mov [di], cx
```

As `di` would point to *toSwap1*, the last instruction I quoted here would overwrite both variables. (This is what would happen if you had set `bp` correctly.)

---

You are missing a program termination call at the end of your *main* function:

```
main: 

    push offset numToNeg
    call refactor
[...]
    mov al, toSwap2
    Call print_al_chr

PROC refactor
```

If this is indeed for a 86-DOS-compatible system, you should add the following after the last call to *print_al_chr*:

```
    mov ax, 4C00h
    int 21h
```

---

Another note: The *param1*, *swap1*, and *swap2* `equ`'s for the stack frame variables could be closer to where these functions that use them are defined. That would make it easier to verify that they are correct.

Comment: another glaring error is that in swap he never actually sets BP and he doesn't seem to have a proper exit before they fall into the functions.

Comment: I just noticed the missing bp initialisation too. Will add it.

Comment: So to fix the problem i need to change the registers I'm using? And to what exactly? :o

Comment: That part of the problem can be fixed by using two partial 8-bit registers, yes, eg `ah` and `al`. Though if you want you can use `al` and `cl` too.

Comment: @Kidsm : use 8 bit registers. In `swap` use `al` and `cl` instead of `ax` and `cx`

Comment: So the problem was that I used registers that are too big for the variables I was using? Why should it affect the output?

Comment: Because you write back from the full 16-bit registers to 16-bit portions of memory. As you reserved only 8 bits for each variable, the last store would overwrite both variables.

Comment: @Kidsm : ecm discussed that in the answer. When you go to write a 16-bit value to a memory location where you have defined data as a byte where do you think the additional 8 bits go? They will get stored in the memory after that which effectively clobbers other data. You say you used a debugger but you should have seen all this if you reviewed the registers and memory before and after you called swap.

Comment: @MichaelPetch

Ehmm I change the registers to what you've suggested, But I'm afraid that it is still not working :( I'm going to edit the question in a second

Comment: @Kidsm : as ecm also said you didn't set BP in `swap`. You need a `mov bp, sp` like you do in `factor`

Comment: Oh I'm a dummy dummy boy, I should have red his comment more deeply :/ Thank you boys. I'm going to make sure for the next time that I'm doing absolutely everything written in your comments

Comment: @Kidsm : I should  have pointed out that when I was referring to AX and CX vs AL and CL I was referring to the `MOV` instructions. If you want to save AX and CX in the function then you can continue to use `push ax` and `push cx` (and the same `pop` instructions)

Comment: @MichaelPetch Well but then My program will not work, So I dont really need AX AND CX anyway. Thank you so much :D

Comment: @Kidsm Why won't your program work if you save and restore AX and CX at the beginning and end of the function. The problem with AX and CX is when you transfer the data to swap to and from memory not on the pushes and pops. DO you understand what push and pop are doing?

Comment: "I should have read his comment more deeply :/ " ecm is a her!

Comment: oh I see, Well is there any disadvantage or a flaw if I use AH and CH?

Comment: @Kidsm By the way I'd recommend doing `push bp` `mov bp, sp` as the first 2 instructions of your function. That way your first parameter is always at BP+2 and second parameter at BP+4 etc. That way it doesn't matter how much data you put on the stack after.

Comment: @MichaelPetch ohh I remember seeing something like that before, I will use it in my next function xD thank you again.

Comment: @Michael Petch: "That way your first parameter is always at BP+2 and second parameter at BP+4 etc." -- Incorrect, with this setup the `word [bp+2]` holds the near return address, `word [bp+4]` is the first parameter.

Comment: @ecm sorry, I actually forgot to account for BP on the stack when I typed that comment.